# Android app with python backend

Tags: java, android, python, neural-network

Hey I created a neural network using python, this network can recognize handwritten digits. I want to use this in my android app. The android app will take a picture of a hand written digit, and send it to the neural network, the neural network will figure out the digit and send it back to the app. How would I do this? I looked at Google Cloud Platform, but I am confused. I want to know how I will send the picture from the app to my python neural network, and send the output back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself familiar with the concepts of REST (RestEasy, Jersey,...), create a REST server with an endpoint that can receive a JSON string which contains your base64 picture. The app converts the picture with base64 and sends it to the REST server. Unencode it in your REST server, delegate it to the python script, convert the result back to JSON and send it back to the app. The app itself receives the JSON and gets the data from it.

This is how I would do it with WildFly server and RestEasy:

```
//app side 
PictureInputBo pictureInputBo = new PictureInputBo([your binary]); //encodes it to base64

//This is working Java code and can be used.
//It will automatically convert to JSON and sent to the "convert" endpoint of the server
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://yourserver:8080/your-webservice/rest/convert/");
Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(pictureInputBo, "application/json;charset=UTF-8;version=1"));


//Server side..."Converter Endpoint", this is also working Java code.
//it will automatically converted back to the Java object "PictureInputBo" by RestEasy
@POST
@Path("/convert")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response convertPicture(@NotNull(message = "Must not be null") @Valid PictureInputBo inputBo)
{
    //Here you pass your business object to the converter service which processes the data
    //(pass it to python or whatever) 
    PictureOutputBo result = converterService.convert(inputBo);

    //Resteasy converts it back to JSON and responds it to the app.
    return Response.ok().entity(result).build();
}


//Back in your app.
check if response.getStatus() == 200) //HTTP Status OK
PictureOutputBo pictureOutputBo = response.readEntity(PictureOutputBo.class);
```